# Illustrator: Lock artboards' content

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

Can you lock all other artboards (or their content) so this gets not affected by any command like "select same stroke colour" etc

Answer (score 3):

There is not an actual way in CC-2014 Illustrator to lock the artboard per the `Artboards` panel I am aware of:

[image]

(`Window -> Artboards` for anyone curious to gain access to it)

I use my Layers Panel (`Window -> Layers` or <kbd>F7</kbd>) and I create a main/top layer called the artboard (example `Artboard_1` then create sub Layers naming them.  I then go back and just lock the layer for that artboard when I do web design mockups:

[image]

Comment: You explained what I was just saying much better than I did :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't lock by artboard; you can only lock by layer or object.

Better practice would be to select everything on an artboard and move it to its own layer (or layer group).

If that's too time-consuming, move the item(s) you want to select to their own layer and lock everything else.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your layer approach. this is an attractive alternative. Meanwhile I discovered the following, which I find quicker, since I'm not the sorting guy.

1) made a shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+I for "Selection>Inverse" - than locking all with CTRL+2 — now you are free to work on the remaining unlocked items

2) custom shortcut ALT+CTRL+SHIFT+I for "isolate Selected Object"
but this works only on separate selections if you group them first before isolating (recognizes not multiple objects but groups, anyways..nailed it

Hope that helps & many thanks for this info!

Hannes